# jQuery run function for identical elements?

Tags: jquery, each, prepend

I have a dozen identical elements whose contents need to be rearranged. I'm sure this is an easy question for jQuery masters, but I'm a total novice and this one has me stumped.

```
<li class="label">
   <div class="title">Card Title</div>
   <div class="content">
      <div class="header"></div>
      <img src="...">
   </div>
</li>
```

Which should look like:

```
<li class="label">
   <div class="content">
      <div class="header">
         <div class="title">Card Title</div>
      </div>
      <img src="...">
   </div>
</li>
```

I've tried to move via `.prependTo()`, but that duplicates every title into *each* label. I was hoping for a function that would say, "for this li.label, move its div.title into div.header", but I can't figure out the proper syntax. I've tried:

`$("div.title").prependTo(".header");`
(moves *every* title into *each* card)

`$($("div.content")[0]).closest("div").prev().prependTo($(".header")[0]);`
(does the job, but only for the 1st card)

```
$("li.label").each(function() 
   {$("div.title").prependTo("div.header")
});
```

(just an embarrassing mess)

A couple things to note:

- I have other lists with labels on the page that I do **not** want this to happen to, so if I could include a filter of `:contains(card)` (or whatever it would be), that would be amazing!
- I am working front-front end; I can only use small scripts to change HTML and style content.

I think I've just mangled this poor language to death, and I'm terribly sorry if the answer is something I should know by now, but any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your idea for selecting which lists to modify. Do they have classes on them or something else you can target, such as parent elements with IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("li.label").each(function(index) {
  if ($(this).find(".title:contains('Card')").length > 0) {
/// cheak if title contans Card
    let title = $(this).find(".title");
    $(this).find(".title").remove();
/// save that elements and then remove it
    $(this).find(".header").append(title);
/// append back title to header
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="label">
  <div class="title">Card Title</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <img src="...">
  </div>
</li>

<li class="label">
  <div class="title">NOT</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <img src="...">
  </div>
</li>

<li class="label">
  <div class="title">Card Title</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <img src="...">
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but you'll want to be more explicit in your selectors. One way is to use an `each()` function along with `$this()`:

```
$('li.label').each(function() {
    // $(this) refers to this particular list item as a jQuery object
    let titleEl = $(this).find('.title');
    let headerEl = $(this).find('.header');

    titleEl.prependTo(headerEl);
});
```

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/2v8dxeqw/)